# Copying cells from one worksheet to another if a column matches a value

Tags: excel

I'm trying to use formula to copy data from one worksheet to another where a column matches a certain value.

To be more specific, I want `Working!A2:E100` to contain `Data!A2:E100` but only for those rows where `Data!C2:100` contains the value "Fixed".

Doing this with leaving blank rows is simple, I just create the formula:

```
 =IF(Data!$C2="Fixed", Data!A2, "")
```

And copy that formula across all the cells.

But then I thought I'd get clever and have it not copy across blank lines, and entered a maze of unclear excel tutorials and vague error messages.

I've created this formula:

```
 =INDEX(Data!A2:Data!A200, MATCH("Fixed", Data!$C$1:Data!$C$200, 0))
```

And entered it as an array formula using ctrl shift enter.

However all I get is the contents of Data!A2 repeated over and over in every cell of my spreadsheet.

Does anyone need to know what I need to do to make this work?

This is my attempt at a local prototype following the example in BruceWayne's answer, the results are visible:

[image: Attempt to get it working]

As you can see "Row 2" just appears repeatedly in the result column. Excel doesn't seem to have an easy way to see what version it is any more but this seems to be a pretty recent one, it's got the ribbon with the file menu and all menu headings are capitalized.

Comment: The Range isn't set correctly in the formula, try this `=INDEX(Data!A2:A200, MATCH("Fixed", Data!$C$1:$C$200, 0))`

Comment: Makes no difference. Still same value in every cell.

Comment: Is there any other value you can use as a lookup?  Since "Fixed" seems to be in multiple cells in column C, the Index/Match is returning the first one it finds.  If you have any other value you could use, you can tweak that.

Comment: Also, just caught it, but you should size the `C1:C200` to `C2:C200` (or switch `A2` to `A1`).  But, per my answer, you can use another formula instead to get you there.

Comment: @BruceWayne I'm specifically looking for all the cells with status Fixed, that's the problem. I'll try the solution you posted tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a formula you can use (note: enter this as an array):

`=IFERROR(INDEX(A$1:A$200,SMALL(IF(C$1:C$200="Fixed",ROW(A$1:A$200)-ROW(A$1)+1),ROWS(A$1:A1))),"")`

You may need to tweak the ranges, I think I got them to match yours, but again, probably need to tweak.  You can then drag this down, and it'll fill in with the values from column A, skipping any blanks.

Edit: Here's a screenshot to (hopefully) help show what I did:
[image]

You can edit the ranges, naturally, to be over two sheets.

To clarify, `A$1:A$200` is the range of what you want to return (the index).  `C$1:C$200` is the range that holds "Fixed".

Comment: I've tried this and I just got blank cells. Is there any way to "break apart" the formula and see it working a step at a time so we can see which bit is breaking?

Comment: @TimB - Sorry about that, I had a typo. I have edited the formula and added a screenshot to help clarify.

Comment: That stops the error but I just see the first value repeated, see edited question.

Comment: @TimB - That's odd - see my edit.  I set it up the same, and get the correct result.  Place the formula first in row 1, and adjust the ranges as necessary.  You can even copy my edited formula (I removed references to `Data!` for clarity) and use it to see.

Comment: Ok, this is interesting. If I paste it into a single cell, then copy that down 1 at a time it works. If I select a block of cells and paste it into all of them it doesn't....

Comment: @TimB - Ahh, Yeah I see now.  Enter the formula in a single cell, as array.  Then you can drag down.  Does that do the trick?  When you select a range and insert the formula all at once (so many cells get the exact same formula), the reason it only returns the first one is because the last part of the formula `Rows(A$1:A1)` will always be the same.  When you enter as separate formulas and drag down, that changes to `Rows(A$1:A2)`, etc. as you drag.